# Xamarin forms : Issue with Deeplinking

Tags: xamarin.forms, deep-linking

I implement deep linking to android part of my Xamarin forms project. But when I click the URL, initially it loads a black page with app name on the top, after a short period only it opens my app. I need to avoid this black screen. Also, the app opens in the same window, no new window is started for my app, if I click the URL from WhatsApp, the app opens in the WhatsApp window.

I need a solution for these 2 problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android manifest set android:name like below:

android:name=".MainActivity"

And in Mainactivity add Name like below:

[Activity(Name = "packagename.MainActivity")]