# Xamarin forms android app black screen issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin app is runs in background, A black screen is appearing before opening the app when we are trying to click and open the deep links to the app. If the app is not opened in background the deep links are working properly.

How to overcome this issue? I need a solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you post some code to try to help you better?

Comment: This is a similar issue, you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534859/xamarin-forms-issue-with-deeplinking?rq=1). Would it be helpful for you? Your prompt reply will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @AiZhang-MSFT I tried this, but it's not worked.

Comment: Anything update? Do you solve your issue now?

Comment: @AiZhang-MSFT No still existing the issue